# Why would my mouse pointer be jerky when it can't get a signal from my router?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, usb, mouse

I've got a fairly new PC but when moving the mouse across the screen, the pointer jerks as if the PC is freezing momentarily every second or so. Strangely, this only seems to happen if the signal from the wifi router is bad. If I move the PC closer to the router to get a full signal, it's fine.

It also seems to affect the keyboard; Opening notepad and holding down a key shows the same momentary freezes.

--
Update:
It's a logitech wireless mouse, and a wired USB logitech keyboard.

Comment: Whether or not it's a wireless mouse will make a big difference to the answers you get...

Comment: @Will - Duly updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've seen this issue with my wireless mouse, as it is in a similar frequency range to wifi - I resolved the issue by moving my wireless mouse dongle further away from the wifi antenna at the rear of my PC.

I'm confused as to why a wired keyboard would suffer the same fate though... something you'll have to come back to if this resolves the wireless mouse issue I guess?!

Comment: Moved the dongle from the back to the front, and all was cured :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably related to the networking and networking drivers in windows.  I've noticed that on some machines when windows is busy with the network it can affect the mouse and launching apps as well.  Everything becomes jerky.

Make sure you have the very latest wireless networking drivers and ensure you've done a windows update as well and see whether that helps.

Comment: This - the networking drivers are more than likely spazzing out and flooding the machine with DPCs, and it's hanging everything else.  I've seen it a lot, and you can see this in action for yourself with this handy tool - http://www.thesycon.de/deu/latency_check.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Go into Device Manager and turn the transmitter power down on your wireless adapter from "Highest"(default) to "Lowest".

Comment: Would this be for the wireless adapter of the WiFi or the mouse/keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved the problem using a USB extension cable. I had no problems when I plugged the Unifying device into a laptop, and this now makes sense, because it was so close to the mouse. I had the Unifying device plugged into the front USB sockets of my desktop PC, but it was on the ground under the desk. Now it is much closer to the mouse there are no more problems.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When the system is encountering network errors and performing retries the network software is apt to "lock out" other activities for brief periods of time.  So the mouse movements (or keyboard clicks) may be being received from the mouse (or keyboard) just fine, but the software can't "service" them.

This may be exacerbated if WiFi and the (dongleless Bluetooth) mouse share the same "radio" hardware in the computer.  Though the two are supposed to operate independently, they may not do so in retry/recovery scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

moving logitech usb to back of computer rather than on top (it was very close to the wifi device) worked for me.  Distance gained by move was only about 2 feet actual, but that was all needed to solve the jerky pointer problem.  Because this worked, I surmise the jerky pointer issue was about Wifi/mouse transmissions interfering with each other as Will suggested.