# Windows 8.1 mouse locked at 30fps on 60fps monitor

Tags: windows-8.1, mouse, desktop, window-manager, fps

On my PC I am able to play a couple of games at 60fps, and my monitor refresh rate is 60fps. However, when I move my mouse around on the desktop and drag Windows from one place to another it's kind of choppy; it looks like it's moving at 30fps to me. I notice on certain YouTube videos some people's mice move incredibly smooth. How do I accomplish this, is it a setting in Windows? (My mouse is completely usable, its just strange how it doesn't look very smooth). I do not have mouse precision on.

EDIT: I have a wireless laser mouse.

Comment: For mice you have "position updates per second", not really frames.  And for USB HID mice, the default is 125 per second, with gaming mice often configured for 1000 updates/second polling rate.  Your wireless signal is quite possible the problem, can you borrow a wired USB mouse and see whether it moves more smoothly?

Comment: Also, are you using a wired or wireless network connection?  Wireless network can interfere with the wireless mouse signal, see http://superuser.com/q/199348/29943

Comment: No I use a wired connection and have Wi-Fi turned off in settings

Comment: I have this problem also. When I open recording applications such as OBS this problem goes away